# How to get the endianness type in PHP?

Tags: php, binary, php-5.3, endianness

In C# I can get the endianness type by this code snippet:

```
if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
   // little-endian is used   
}
else
{
   // big-endian is used
}
```

How can I do the same in PHP?

Comment: Detect the endianness of *what* specifically?

Comment: For example when using socket_send($socket, $data, $len). Which endianness is used?

Comment: `$data` is an 8-bit binary string, a `char` sequence (like all php strings). It has no endianness.  If you need to prepare binary data in a specific endianness, use the [`pack()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [`unpack()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) functions.

Comment: If you want to get the current machine endian order, you can use `pack()` with the format option `l` or `L` and a constant input and evaluate the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP's string type is an 8-bit binary string, a `char` sequence. It has no endianness.  Thus for the most part endianness is a non-issue in PHP.

If you need to prepare binary data in a specific endianness, use the [`pack()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [`unpack()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) functions.

If you need to determine the machine's native endianness, you can use `pack()` and `unpack()` in the same way.

```
function isLittleEndian() {
    $testint = 0x00FF;
    $p = pack('S', $testint);
    return $testint===current(unpack('v', $p));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, where can I find a machine which returns false? :-)

Comment: A PowerPC should return false. If you never run on bigendian machines, why ask the question?

Comment: Because I don't know exaclty what machines my clients are using.

Answer (score 8):

```
function isLittleEndian() {
    return unpack('S',"\x01\x00")[1] === 1;
}
```

Little-endian systems store the least significant byte in the smallest (left-most) address. Thus the value `1`, packed as a "short" (2-byte integer) should have its value stored in the left byte, whereas a big-endian system would store it in the right byte.